# delay method not working with my funciton

Tags: jquery

Trying to get a one second delay when this function is called however it is not delaying. what am i doing wrong?

```
function currentGrassColor(){
    var grassField = $('.currentProgram_grassBg').find('img');
    grassField.delay(1000).attr('src', 'img/grassRed.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to set a delay

```
function currentGrassColor(){
    var grassField = $('.currentProgram_grassBg').find('img'); 
    setTimeout(function(){grassField.attr('src', 'img/grassRed.png');},1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
function currentGrassColor(){
    var grassField = $('.currentProgram_grassBg').find('img');
    setTimeout(function(){
        grassField.prop('src', 'img/grassRed.png');
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a timeout or, if using delay(), you need to put relative code to delay in queue:

```
function currentGrassColor() {
    var grassField = $('.currentProgram_grassBg').find('img');
    grassField.delay(1000).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).attr('src', 'img/grassRed.png');
        next();
    });
}
```